# Problem reaching flask app in docker-compose

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

yet another docker/flask question.
I'm having problems connecting to my flask app from another container in `docker-compose`.

My **dockerfile** sets up a flask app like:

```
COPY ./ /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN find -name "*.pyc" -delete && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

The app runs on `0.0.0.0:5000`, the **docker-compose.yml** looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  test:
    image: alpine:3.8
```

Now after `docker-compose up` I can `curl` from the host like:

```
curl -i http://0.0.0.0:5000
...
200 - ok
```

but if I jump into the test container I get a 404:

```
docker-compose run test sh
# apk --update add curl
# curl -i http://app:5000
...
404 - not found
```

Actually these 2 containers should *see* each other, and indeed when I look at the logs of `app` I can see the requests from `test` comming in.
But they are answered with 404.

What am I doing wrong here?

Btw, I have a minimal example here: https://github.com/mRcSchwering/flask_docker-compose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your config

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = '0.0.0.0:5000'
```

Your Flask thinks its name is `0.0.0.0:5000`, therefore not responding to others.

To verify, call `curl -H Host:0.0.0.0:5000 -i http://app:5000` from test.

You can remove this config and run the server with

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks. I always thought setting server_name is the same as setting host and port (arguments)

Comment: Also, make sure to `docker-compose up <service>` not `docker-compose run <service>`.